# Troubleshoot Current PHP Login Form

Tags: php, sql, forms, authentication, passwords

I really need your help. Our boss wants me to check why he cannot access on the login form that was made by our previous developer before, and requested if I could do reset or update their passwords. I am new to PHP and sql but I do basic knowledge on them.

I have tried to reset the password using the phpmysql but still the cannot access always displays and error message

> Invalid Login Info!

Can you please guys help me with this? Bellow is the script that our previous developer.

```
<?php
  include("./inc.config.php");
  include("./inc.utils.php");
  include("./inc.mysql.php");
    include("./inc.sysprod.php");
    $db = new sql_db(HOST, USER, PASS, DB, false);  
    $sCompName = GetCompName($db);
  session_start();
  if ($_POST["sc_submit"])
  {
    if (isset($_POST["uname"]) && isset($_POST["pword"]))
    {
      $db = new sql_db(HOST, USER,PASS, DB, false);
      $sSQL = "SELECT member_code, nickname FROM members WHERE user_name = '".uAddSlashes($_POST["uname"])."' ".
              "AND pass_word = password('".uAddSlashes($_POST["pword"])."') ";
      $rResult = $db->sql_query($sSQL);
      if ($db->sql_numrows($rResult) == 1)
      {
        if (!isset($_SESSION["sc_mcode"]))
        {
            $rRow = $db->sql_fetchrow();
            $_SESSION["sc_mcode"] = $rRow["member_code"];
            $_SESSION["sc_nname"] = $rRow["nickname"];
            $_SESSION["sc_stime"] = adjustTime(TIME_OFFSET, mktime());
                    $_SESSION["sc_productcode"] = "";
                    $_SESSION["sc_mlastname"] = "";
                    $_SESSION["sc_mfirstname"] = "";
                    $_SESSION["sc_maddress"] = "";
                    $_SESSION["sc_memail"] = "";
                    $_SESSION["sc_mcontactno"] = "";
                    $_SESSION["sc_rcode"] = "";
                    $_SESSION["sc_rlastname"] = "";
                    $_SESSION["sc_rfirstname"] = "";
                    $_SESSION["sc_remail"] = "";
                    $_SESSION["sc_raddress"] = "";
                    $_SESSION["sc_rcontactno"] = "";
                    $_SESSION["sc_vquestion"] = "";
                    $_SESSION["sc_vanswer"] = "";
                    $_SESSION["sc_center"] = "";


          $db = new sql_db(HOST, USER, PASS, DB, false);
          $sSQL = "INSERT INTO logs SET session = '".$_COOKIE[session_name()]."', ".
                  "member_code = '".uAddSlashes($_SESSION["sc_mcode"])."', ".
                  "start_login = '".$_SESSION["sc_stime"]."', ".
                  "last_login = '".$_SESSION["sc_stime"]."' ";
          $rResult = $db->sql_query($sSQL);
          $eError = $db->sql_error();
          $db->sql_close();
          header("Location: sendinfo.php");
        }
      }
      else {
        $invalid = 1;
      }
    }
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $sCompName; ?></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<LINK HREF="layout.css" REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css">
</head>

<body>
<TABLE WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%" BORDER="0" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0">
  <FORM NAME="frmLogin" METHOD="POST" ACTION="login.php">
  <TR>
        <TD ALIGN="CENTER"><TABLE BORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0">

          <TR ALIGN="CENTER">

            <TD HEIGHT="30" COLSPAN="2" CLASS="Text">Login Here</TD>
          </TR>
      <?php
                if ($invalid == 1) {
          ?>
          <TR ALIGN="CENTER">
                        <TD HEIGHT="30" COLSPAN="2" CLASS="Text"><FONT COLOR="#FF0000"><? echo "Invalid username and/or password!"; ?></FONT></TD>
          </TR>
      <?php } ?>
          <TR>

            <TD HEIGHT="30" CLASS="Text">&nbsp;username&nbsp;</TD>
            <TD HEIGHT="30" CLASS="Text1">
                          <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="uname" CLASS="Fields" STYLE="width:150px;">
                  </TD>
          </TR>

          <TR>

            <TD HEIGHT="30" CLASS="Text">&nbsp;password&nbsp;</TD>
            <TD HEIGHT="30" CLASS="Text1"><INPUT NAME="pword" TYPE="password" CLASS="Fields" STYLE="width:150px;">

                  </TD>
          </TR>

          <TR ALIGN="CENTER">

                        <TD HEIGHT="30" COLSPAN="2">
                          <INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="sc_submit" VALUE="log-in" CLASS="Fields" STYLE="width:100px;"></TD>
          </TR>
          </TABLE></TD>
  </TR>
  </FORM>
</TABLE>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know what happen on this. Before I did troubleshoot the same problem but this time is very hard for me.

Answer (score 0):

I notice on phpmyadmin when updating the password by choosing the function PASSWORD on password field there was an error

> Warning: #1265 Data truncated for column

I tried to changed the function to md5 or old_password as well as changing the type on the script:

```
"AND pass_word = password('".uAddSlashes($_POST["pword"])."') ";
```

to

```
"AND pass_word = md5('".uAddSlashes($_POST["pword"])."') ";
```

And it works now. Thank you so much.. I do not know what the error means